# How to request cross domain with Aurelia using http-client

Tags: javascript, cors, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, aurelia

I have a simple Data Resource that retrieves a flat json file from within my own project. When I try to replace the `url` with that of a Working API end point that I have running on a separate domain I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error in chrome.

**SETUP:** I have a Visual Studio solution with two projects.

1) **RateAppAPI** (WebAPI Project w/ [AspNet.cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/))
2) **RateAppClient** (ASPNET 5 Template w/ [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/what-is-aurelia))
3) I have both a **flat file** and an **API endpoint** serving up the same json document. You will see one commented in the code and the other un-commented.

1. The API project is serving my GetAll route with no problems, I can
   hit the endpoint using postman and I get back a large result of
   Json. I have CORS enabled and setup properly, I have ruled that out
   as an issue.
2. I have the client project running Aurelia in the wwwroot directory
   and I am using [aurelia-http-client](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/blob/master/doc/article/en-US/http-services.md#aurelia-http-client) which I will provide the code
   for, but I will tell you that the example I will provide works with
   no problems using the flat file that I have in a directory within
   the client project.
3. As long as I point the Get() request at the flat file within my own project  (of course) I have no issues pulling in the data and working with it. It is only when I switch the url to point at the endpoint that is on a different domain that I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error.

Here is my code (an ES6 [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/what-is-aurelia) module) that is the Data Resource:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-http-client";

let baseURL = "http://localhost/RateAppAPI/api/UtilZip/ByUtil/7";
//let baseURL = "../api/utilzip/utilzip.json";

@inject(HttpClient)

export class UtilZipData {

constructor(httpClient) {
    this.http = httpClient;
    this.http.configure(x => { x.withCredentials(); });
}

getAll() {
    return this.http.get(baseURL)
        .then(response => {
            return response.content;
        });
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, I need to figure out how to use only Windows Auth and be able to run a client application from one domain, lets call that domain `localhost:1234` and access a different domain, lets call the API domain `localhost/RatAppAPI` The API will have CORS enabled using the following method:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1234/", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently, key problem is the API endpoint authorization. I don't know `windows-authentication` to say further, but it should not be specific to Aurelia or its `http-client`. Hope this comment is helpful for those who found it misleading like me.

Comment: I just gave a full picture of what I was doing here. I'm not sure where the problem lies. It seems like this should work, but somewhere (in the API) or in the client application, I am doing something wrong between my http get and the authorization by the API to access that end point.

Comment: Eric, just drop the trailing forward slash in your allowed origin and everything should start working...

Comment: It;s working, I will update the Question with a retrospective and what I learned. lol As this can be very tricky if you enable cors multiple times in the project and set multiple origins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should try is dropping the trailing forward slash in the origin. I am pretty sure that is what is causing some issues for you:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1234/", "*", "*");
//Should be the following instead
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1234", "*", "*");
```

Also assuming you are going to be hosting on IIS and you are looking to apply the same CORS policy globally to all your controller actions, then you can do it from the config as well:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <httpProtocol>
           <customHeaders>
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1234" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
               <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
           </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also the IIS Options handler may interfere with things, so make sure that it is removed i.e.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    ...
       <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
    ...
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

As a last resort you can also try disabling CORS security in chrome by either starting it with the following arguments  `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir` or creating an alias in your host file for localhost and using that instead.This shouldn't really be required if all the headers have been set properly though.

Another thing, since you are looking to send through credentials, you won't be able to use a wildcard for the allowed domain. I guess that goes without saying :). With that being said you may also need to do the following:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:1234", "*", "*")
{
    SupportsCredentials = true
};
```

Comment: First off, thank you for your time. As I figured it was on the Web API side, but I wasn't sure and that is why I gave the full story. A combination of removing the forward slash and only setting the origin in one place seems to have been the resolution. Let me do a few tests and I will provide my findings in a retro.

Comment: No problem at all, I was more than happy to help. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes to spot something like this.

Comment: I'd like to better understand everything and I have found some interesting and baffling responses and I even turned off enable cors and was able to run my client and use the resource. Very strange. But it is working. You thin if I hosted some images and some explanations of my findings you would take a look at it?

Comment: Sure, happy to take a look at it. Sounds a bit odd that you were able to access the resource from the client with CORS turned off. You may want to rule out caching as part of that. Those pesky GET requests love being cached :)

Comment: Absolutely. Will check that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following in my API Global.asax

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    string httpOrigin = Request.Params["HTTP_ORIGIN"] ?? "*";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpOrigin);

    //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, dataType");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        var httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
        httpApplication?.CompleteRequest();
    }
}
```